# Clear SMS Notification From Notification Drawer after deleting SMS from Broadcast

Tags: android, notifications, sms, broadcast

After Successfully deleting an SMS from Broadcast, i cant clear notification from notification drawer

1)when i open sms app, that sms is deleted,
  but in notification, shows sms with msg

2)when i click on sms notification, it opens 'sms app with new blank sms'

i tried to clear notification drawer by:
(1)

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) supercontext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

i tried to clear notification drawer by:
(2)

```
Intent closeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
closeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
supercontext.startActivity(closeIntent);
```

But still msg is visible in Notification Drawer
here is my code in Broadcast.java:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    supercontext = context;
    try {
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                senderNum = phoneNumber;
                message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                deleteSMSHandler()
           }

public void deleteSMSHandler() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                deleteSMS(supercontext, message, senderNum);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
}

public void deleteSMS(Context context, String message, String number) {
    try {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
                new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address",
                        "person", "date", "body"}, null, null, null);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                long id = c.getLong(0);
                long threadId = c.getLong(1);
                String where = "address=" + number;
                where = "thread_id=" + threadId;
                String address = c.getString(2);
                String body = c.getString(5);
                if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), where, null);

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) supercontext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.cancelAll();

                    Intent closeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                    closeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    supercontext.startActivity(closeIntent);
                }
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Delete MSG Error", "" + e);
        String x = e + "";
        //mLogger.logError("Could not delete SMS from inbox: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

here is my manifests file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.sagarmakhija1994.Framework.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.sagarmakhija1994.Framework.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

> After Successfully deleting an SMS from Broadcast

You cannot delete an SMS on Android 4.4+, unless you are the user's chosen SMS client.

> But still msg is visible in Notification Drawer

Correct. That `Notification` was raised by the SMS app. The SMS app can clear it. On Android 4.4+, your app would have to *be* the SMS app, and so you would `cancel()` your own `Notification`.

You could implement [a `NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) and use that to forcibly clear the SMS. The user would have to agree, in Settings, to let you spy on all the user's notifications. Few users would do this. And `NotificationListenerService` is only available on Android 4.3+. Hence, the only version of Android for which you would get any value from it would be Android 4.3.

> here is my manifests file

Please note that several of the permissions that you have listed are ones that only system apps can hold.

Comment: You cannot delete an SMS on Android 4.4+,

but i done it, above code is perfectly deleting sms.
i tested in both android 5.1 and 4.4

just i want to clear notification.
may b done it by fore close msg app

just want to know, how i force close sms app
like the greenyfy app do

Comment: You cannot delete an SMS on Android 4.4+,

but the above code is working fine
it successfully deletes the sms in both android 5.1 and 4.4

i just want to clear notification of that sms

when i open the sms app after deleting the sms by Reciver
the notification get clear and there is no sms which i deleted by Reciver

but problem is till i m not opening sms app the sms is visible and readable by user in notification drawer

Comment: @SagarMakhija: Your device is unusual. [Only the user's chosen SMS client can write to the SMS provider starting with Android 4.4](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).